# NodeJS Cannot read property 'length' of undefined - MagicMirror Module

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, electron, magic-mirror

I'm working on a prototype of a MagicMirror Module that pulls data in from this json feed https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1. It passes fine on json parse payload But fails somewhere in within tArray length with cannot ready property 'length' of undefined. I'm suspecting the JSON isn't being carried to tArray properly, but i'm a at a loss. Below are my two files!

**node_helper.js**

```
'use strict';

/* Magic Mirror
 * Module:
 */

const NodeHelper = require('node_helper');
var request = require('request');
var moment = require('moment');

module.exports = NodeHelper.create({

    start: function() {
        this.started = false;
        this.config = null;
    },

    getData: function() {
        var self = this;
        var myUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";
        request({
            url: myUrl,
            method: 'GET',
            headers: { 'API_TOKEN': this.config.apiKey }
        }, function (error, response, body) {
            console.log(body);
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                self.sendSocketNotification("DATA", body);
            }
        });

        setTimeout(function() { self.getData(); }, this.config.refreshInterval);
    },

    socketNotificationReceived: function(notification, payload) {
        var self = this;
        if (notification === 'CONFIG' && self.started == false) {
            self.config = payload;
            self.sendSocketNotification("STARTED", true);
            self.getData();
            self.started = true;
        }
    }
});
```

**MMM-Fi.js**

```
/* Magic Mirror

 */

Module.register('MMM-Fi',{

    defaults: {
        animationSpeed: 1000,
        refreshInterval: 1000 * 60, //refresh every minute
        updateInterval: 1000 * 3600, //update every hour
        lang: config.language,
        initialLoadDelay: 0, // 0 seconds delay
        retryDelay: 5,
    },

    // Define required scripts.
    getScripts: function() {
        return ["moment.js", "font-awesome.css"];
    },

    getStyles: function() {
        return ['MMM-Fi.css'];
    },

    start: function() {
        Log.info('Starting module: ' + this.name);
        this.loaded = false;
        this.sendSocketNotification('CONFIG', this.config);
    },

    getDom: function() {
        var wrapper = document.createElement("div");

        if (this.config.apiKey === "") {
            wrapper.innerHTML = "No Fi <i>apiKey</i> set in config file.";
            wrapper.className = "dimmed light small";
            return wrapper;
        }

        if (this.config.googleApiKey === "") {
            wrapper.innerHTML = "No Google <i>api Key</i> set in config file.";
            wrapper.className = "dimmed light small";
            return wrapper;
        }

        if (!this.loaded) {
            wrapper.innerHTML = this.translate('LOADING');
            wrapper.className = "dimmed light small";
            return wrapper;
        }

        if (!this.tArray.length) {
            wrapper.innerHTML = "No data";
            wrapper.className = "dimmed light small";
            return wrapper;
        }

        var table = document.createElement("table");
        table.id = "fitable";
        table.className = "small thin light";

        var row = document.createElement("tr");

        var lineHeader = document.createElement("th");
        lineHeader.innerHTML = "test2";
        lineHeader.colSpan = 2;
        row.appendChild(lineHeader);
        table.appendChild(row);

        for (var i in this.tArray) {
            var currentDeparture = this.tArray[i];
            console.log(currentDeparture.title)
        }
        wrapper.appendChild(table);
        return wrapper;
    },

    tFi: function(data) {
        if (!data.listT) {
            return;
        }

    this.tArray = [];
    for (var i in data.listT) {
        var t = data.listT[i];
        this.tArray.push({
            userId: t.userId,
            id: t.id,
            title: t.title,
            completed: t.completed,
        });

    }

    return;
},
    socketNotificationReceived: function(notification, payload) {
            if (notification === "STARTED") {
                this.updateDom();
            }
            else if (notification === "DATA") {
                this.loaded = true;
                this.tFi(JSON.parse(payload));
                this.updateDom();
            }
    }

});
```

Comment: `this.tArray` is created and populated in `tFi` - is `tFi` execute before `getDom` - simplest fix ... `if (!this.tArray || !this.tArray.length) {`

Comment: if `getDom()` is called before `tFi()`, `tArray` will not be initialized and so when you check `this.tArray.length` it will error. You would need to check `if(!this.tArray || !this.tArray.length)`

Comment: oh wow! Thank you both so much. That was it